# How to get userid at wp_logout action hook?

Tags: users

I need to perform some cleanup after a user logged out, so I added a wp_logout action hook. Problem is, wp_get_current_user() already returns null if called from within the wp_logout action hook. How do I get the logging out users userid inside a wp_logout action hook?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about hooking `'clear_auth_cookie'` with the cleaning you need to do? If you need even more depth, you can outright replace `wp_clear_auth_cookie()`, but that can get into issues where it will conflict with other plugins, so avoid that if possible.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I have used this hook for a custom audit plugin, to record the logout event. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

*Update (previous edit contained inaccuracy)*:

As [source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/6.0/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L671) suggests too, you can now use

```
function logout_redirect765($user_id){
    ...
}
add_action('wp_logout','logout_redirect765');
```

Answer (score -4):

```
add_action('wp_logout', 'user_id');

function user_id()
{
    wp_get_current_user()->data->ID;
}
```

use this in plugin main file

Comment: As the OP states 'wp_get_current_user() already returns null if called from within the wp_logout action hook' -- so this won't work.